# Odd number of bits in ADC

Tags: adc

Why is it that most ADC have even number of bit resolution like 8, 10, 12, 14 bits etc. Odd numbers are not available.

Comment: how about [this](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/ADC1112D125.pdf)

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/35544/effective-number-of-bits-of-14-bit-adc?rq=1 is tangentially relevant; how many of your bits are real bits?

Comment: ive seen 11 bit ADC before.

Answer (score 2):

Well, actually, odd numbers ARE available. You just have to look ;)

Here's an example: ADC1112D125 : http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/ADC1112D125.pdf

Answer (score 2):

In radio astronomy, the signals from pairs of antennas are multiplied then put through a very fast low-res ADC. These are rarely as much as 8 bits.  Some are 3-bit, some are 2-bit, and, amazing but true, real science can be done with 1-bit ADCs.   Of course, a 1-bit ADC is really no more than a simple threshold detector.

Have a look at https://science.nrao.edu/facilities/vla/docs/manuals/oss2013a/performance/samplers
or https://science.nrao.edu/facilities/vla/docs/manuals/oss2013b/performance/correlator/referencemanual-all-pages

Comment: 30-bit? Didn't you mean 3bit?

Comment: It's the first time I've heard of 1-bit ADC http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/59341/what-is-a-one-bit-adc-good-for?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Of the 5,161 ADC's that are currently in stock at Digi-Key, 64 (about 1%) have an odd number of bits of resolution: 9, 11, 13, 15, 19 and 31 bits.  So they are a rare breed.

What sets the odd-numbered ADC's apart from the others is that *all* 64 appear to have differential inputs.  How that relates to them having a odd number of bits of resolution I don't know.

Comment: I wonder if your parametric search went astray, I found quite a few single-ended ones with odds bits for example: http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/AD7861APZ/AD7861APZ-ND/997890

Comment: Note it says: Digi-Key Stock: 0.  As my answer says, "Of the 5,161 ADCs that are currently in stock".  Digi-Keys actually has 16,577 ADC's in their catalog, but only about 1/3 are stocked.  As a matter of principle, I ignore anything Digi-Key doesn't list as in-stock.  If I can't get it overnight, forget it.

Comment: Ahh yes missed that part.